# Escape all the characters in a pattern except some metachars

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I want to allow the user use a `"*"` metachar in search and would like to use the pattern entered by user with `Pattern.compile`. So I would have to escape all the other metachars that user enters except the `*`. I am doing it with the below code, is there a better way of doing this?

```
private String escapePattern(String pattern) {
        final String PATTERN_MATCH_ALL = ".*"; 
        if(null == pattern || "".equals(pattern.trim())) { 
            return PATTERN_MATCH_ALL;
        }
        String remaining = pattern;
        String result = "";
        int index;
        while((index = remaining.indexOf("*")) >= 0) { 
            if(index > 0) {
                result += Pattern.quote(remaining.substring(0, index)) + PATTERN_MATCH_ALL;
            }
            if(index < remaining.length()-1) {
                remaining = remaining.substring(index + 1);
            } else
                remaining = "";
        }
        return result + Pattern.quote(remaining) + PATTERN_MATCH_ALL;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to improve?  Readability?  Performance?  Conciseness?

Comment: the code i have writted is very verbose, as well i wanted was to use any inbuilt functionality that would do this for me instead of me doing this myself. so both readability, conciseness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
"\\Q" + pattern.replace("*", "\\E.*\\Q") + "\\E";
```